# mysql Trigger Issue "in wrong schema"

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am running

```
delimiter //
create trigger beforeYourTableUpdate  BEFORE UPDATE on YourTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.guid_column := (SELECT UUID());
END
//

delimiter; [edit]

UPDATE YourTable set guid_column = (SELECT UUID());

DROP TRIGGER beforeYourTableUpdate;
```

And everytime I run this - I get the error "Trigger in wrong schema" using MySQL 5.5

Any ideas why this would be ?

Comment: You didn't reset your delimiter. Is that just an omission for the question?

Comment: hey @nanne - whoops no - want to provide a solution so can select it ? :)

Comment: Sure :D. Would've been a sub-optimal answer if you just skipped it in the example, and i didn't know it could produce this error, that's why I commented :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't reset the delimiter, you might want to add

```
delimiter ;
```

Comment: tried that just then but still get the same error "Trigger in wrong schema" ? i added the edit to original question

Comment: what is `new.guid_column` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the schema you're working with. On the top, add:

```
use 'yourWorkingSchema';
```

That should solve the problem.